# cordova geolocation is not working in ionic(Android)

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, geolocation

Google has deprecated the methods getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() from insecure origins. As I am developing an android application using ionic framework I cant use HTTPS. So I tried to use Cordova geolocation plugin but it is also not working. The code snippet of Cordova plugin is

```js
$scope.getLocation = function () {
        alert('Get location Called')
        var posOptions = {
            timeout: 10000,
            enableHighAccuracy: false
        }
        $cordovaGeolocation
            .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
            .then(function (position) {
                alert('getting current position')
                var lat = position.coords.latitude
                alert(lat)
                var long = position.coords.longitude
                alert(long)
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err)
                alert(err.message)
            })
    }
```

```html
<button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="getLocation()">
            Get Location
        </button>
```

It gives me an error in console.log(err) like

```
PositionError {message: "Timeout expired", code: 3, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3}
```

I only want to get the current position of the user. Is there any other way I could use to get the current latitude and longitude?

Comment: try *remove plugin* and then install *again*.

Comment: @Vaibhav If you are testing on device, could you reboot the device once? Also Go to Settings -> Location and security -> Use networks; and active it

Comment: @Atula I tried removing plugin and install it again but it is not working

Comment: have you tried @Gandhi's adivce. See this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239846/android-geolocation-using-phonegap-code-3-error

Comment: @Atula I tried Gandhi's advice and its working now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Gandhi Thank You for your advice :)

Comment: glad to know @VaibhavGole

Comment: @VaibhavGole Glad it worked. You can accept the answer so that it can be helpful for others too. Cheers

Comment: @VaibhavGole: I tried each and everything but nothing worked for me.watchPosition is not fire in some android devices.i have already check the GPS and i am not getting any error in console.i used cordova 7.0.0 and android 6.4.0 tell me what i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing on device, you can reboot the device once. Also Go to Settings -> Location and security -> Use networks and active it. This should help.