# Getting "Position Error Timeout" Error in cordova geolocation plugin : Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

We are getting error while fetching the location in ionic. Every time we are getting "Position Error"

```
PositionError {code: 3, message: "Timeout expired"}
```

In very rare case its working , If I reboot my phone then for few time its working,

How can I make it consistent? Every time i want to fetch location value?

Is there any plugin available ?

Please check below code

```
var posOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 60000
        };


$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {


               $scope.loadingIndicator.hide();
               $scope.lat  = position.coords.latitude
               $scope.long = position.coords.longitude


        }, function(err) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
             var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: '',
              template: 'Try Again! Not able to get current location'
            })
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Can you post your code from where you are trying to access the location here?

Comment: Also regardless of the code, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239846/android-geolocation-using-phonegap-code-3-error

Comment: check updated code

Comment: I'm using cordova geolocation plugin with Ionic native, on Ionic 3. It's not working, If I use a timeout value I receive a timeout error. Wihtout a timeout value I never have a response. GPS is enabled on Android tablet, the gps icon on status bar is appearing. I never have a response with coords

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and find a solution by doing this:

1. Add the plugin whitelist:
   ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
2. I assume that u already installed this:
   ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
3. Don't forget to do a npm install each time you change dependencies.
4. And then you can use : 
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, positionOption)

instead of cordovaGeoLocation.

If you still with your problem, try a fresh code following this repo :

https://github.com/jessamynsmith/ionic-angular-google-maps-example 
to check if you make it all well.

Good luck !

Comment: I'm using cordova geolocation plugin with Ionic native, on Ionic 3. It's not working, If I use a timeout value I receive a timeout error. Wihtout a timeout value I never have a response. GPS is enabled on Android tablet, the gps icon on status bar is appearing. I never have a response with coords

Comment: As the example we have mention is in IONIC 1, you should make a new post with your problem in IONIC 3 (if you cant find another answer), then we could help you, good luck !